# Relationship between files and posts in SQL-Alchemy Back End

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want users to be able to upload files associated with posts.  This is going to be a many to one relationship, where a post can have multiple files.  Not all uploaded files will be related to posts.  What should I do to create a relationship between files and posts that makes sense?  Should I create a new table to handle this or add a column that is left blank if the file isn't related to a post?  Or is there a more traditional way of doing this?